# добавить sass в существующий Angular 5 проект

Tags: sass, angular5

Как добавить sass в каждый компонент существующего проекта?

Comment: Что значит добавить sass?

Comment: ng set defaults.styleExt sass
значит, что нужно помимо scss подкинуть sass

Answer (score 1):

Способ решения таков:
CLI локальный и проектный должны быть одной версии
Затем ng set defaults.styleExt sass